# Unable to remove mailbox permissions through PowerShell on Exchange 2010 SP1

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Using Exchange 2010 SP1 remote powershell, I added permissions for a user using the Add-MailboxPermission cmdlet. Here's the command I used to add permissions...

`Add-MailboxPermission user_mailbox -User admin_user -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All`

It worked great. Once I ran it, admin_user had access to user_mailbox's mailbox. Now, when I try to remove those permissions, it fails. Here's the command I used to remove permissions...

`Remove-MailboxPermission user_mailbox -User admin_user -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All`

And here's the error it gave...

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-MailboxPermission], Nu 
   llReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoteHostExecutionException`

I'm not sure what this exception means so I'm not sure where to look. Is there any other way to remove mailbox permissions through remote powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity "user_mailbox" -User "user_with_permission_to_remove" | Remove-MailboxPermission
```

Comment: AccessRights parameter is not optional, so this would not work.

Comment: Good catch. Adjusted the command to use Get-MailboxPermission instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a corrupt mailbox permission with a user on Exchange 2013. A user had permission to a mailbox using inherited AND specific permissions. Just doing a Remove-MailboxPermission wasn't quite enough. I had to get the permissions then remove the permissions. It removed the corrupted one and skipped the inherited one.

Get-MailboxPermission -identity  | Where {$_.user -eq ""} | Remove-MailboxPermission.

Worked like a charm.